# Slow Entity Spatial Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create a method to lookup locations stored in my entity database. I am attempting to do this using the DbGeography class and in soem cases i am having success but often the operation times out.

The data set i am working with is around 420,000 records and often my queries take around 30 seconds when they don't fail. Is this normal performance for my current usage?

This is my code,

```
        private List<TransportStop> StopsNearby(double latitude, double longitude, double radiusInKm)
    {
        var location = CreatePoint(latitude, longitude);

        var radiusInMeters = radiusInKm * 1000;

        var stops =
            from c in Data.Naptans
            let distance = c.L.Distance(location)
            where distance <= radiusInMeters
            select c;


        return stops.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the logging for the SQL generated by entity framework? Do you have any indexes on your SQL table?

Comment: @Wazner I am not sure indexes will help with a geographic query (unless SQL is a lot smarter than I expect about it).

Comment: Apparently you can use a spatial index in SQL Server if you meet a bunch of criteria for a [Nearest Neighbor Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor).

Comment: Try hitting the database with a direct SQL query, taking your code completely out of the equation. Then you'll be able to determine if the problem is the DBMS or your code. We had a similar problem that turned out to be caused by SQL Azure throttling on the cheaper pricing tiers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your method to Task like that:

```
public Task<List<TransportStop>> StopsNearby(double latitude, double longitude, double radiusInKm)
    {
        var location = CreatePoint(latitude, longitude);

        var radiusInMeters = radiusInKm * 1000;

        var stops =
            from c in Data.Naptans
            let distance = c.L.Distance(location)
            where distance <= radiusInMeters
            select c;


        return stops.ToList();
    }
```

And then the reference to call this method is like that:

```
public async Task Test()
    {
        var stopsNearby = await StopsNearby(1, 1, 1);
    }
```

Comment: I was somewhat sceptical as to why making the method an async Task would have any effect but i did try anyway. Sadly the result is the same. Can you explain why you thought this might be the solution?

Comment: "i am having success but often the operation times out." I thought about making the Task method, wait until it finished completely to avoid the time out.